# how to set containable behavior + cakephp2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

[image]

here is my containable condition

```
$userStatusCondition = array('AND' => array(
                                                     'OR'=> array(
                                                                    'TransactionStatus.buyer_status_id'=>$user_status_id,
                                                                    'TransactionStatus.seller_status_id'=>$user_status_id,
                                                                )
                                                            )
                                                );
```

Merge conditions (other conditions + user_status condition)

```
$transactions = $this->Transaction->find('all',array(
                                                            'conditions'=> Set::merge($otherConditions, $userStatusCondition),
                                                            'recursive'=>2));
```

in TransactionModel I set the

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');

public $belongsTo = array(
             'UserStatus' => array(
        'className' => 'UserStatus',
        'foreignKey' => 'buyer_status_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
            'UserStatus' => array(
        'className' => 'UserStatus',
        'foreignKey' => 'seller_status_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
   );
```

problems

1) I don't like to use recursive 2: it decreases the find method - how ever I think after containable correctly I think I need to remove recursive
2) I have four user_statuses in User_Status table 1)waiting 2)attention 3)block 4)Complete which I want to find transactions filtered by buyer_status_id or seller_status_id

I donno how to create new behavior - there is small article about it 
[Using Contain](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have four user_statuses in User_Status table 1)waiting 2)attention 3)block 4)Complete which I want to find transactions filtered by buyer_status_id or seller_status_id

Comment: Instead of using containable I answered an Alternative way. Hope it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of linking to table relationship is to use bindModel to force Join.
Below is a code that binds 4 tables Items->Categories->Sections->divisions. You can find anything within the range of the relationship.

```
$this->unbindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array('Category')
));

$this->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'Category' => array(
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Category.id = Item.category_id')
        ),
        'Section' => array(
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Section.id = Category.section_id')
        )
        'Division' => array(
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Division.id = Section.division_id')
        )
    )
));
$result = $this->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Item.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array('Category', 'Section', 'Division'),
    'fields' => array('Division.id')
));
```

By doing this you can freely query anything in the range of the tables. 
More Info here: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations

Comment: Thank you body. I read this article but I couldn't implement it because it is not in-depth. I will give it a try again now. I let you know - Do I still need to use public $actsAs = array('Containable');  in TransactionModel

Comment: I have successfully implemented it myself I'm sure you can also. Cheers

Comment: You don't have to necessarily put $actsAs = array('Containable');. Make sure you checked the right conditions in binding model.

Comment: I have used it in TransactionController but it is not working :(