# CakePHP Tree-Node-like behaviour on model

Tags: cakephp, binary-tree, nodes, depth-first-search

I'm currently working on a project in which I'm going to need to create a binary-tree structure on a model. It's something similar to "A person can have 2 friends. Each of those 2 friends are persons as well, so they can also have 2 friends each one." Finally I will need to do a depth-first node search.

I want to do a depth search up to 4 levels, and I also want to know if any of the levels are uncompleted, for example:

```
                                       person(root)

                  person(branch A)                     person(branch B)

        person             person              person             person

    person   person    person   person      (no children)     (only 1 child)person
```

as you can see, **branch A** is complete up to 4 levels. but **branch B** is not.

I'm guessing the way to know which branch is complete and which one isn't is to verify using `empty()` function on the `array`, something like:

```
$person = $this->Person->find('first', $conditions);
if(empty($person['Person']['friend_1'])) 
    $uncomplete = true;
```

I'm missing the algorithm to iterate through nodes here, but what I really need is how do I retrieve 4 depths of `hasOne` / `belongsTo` (not sure which one is it), is it setting `Model::recursive = 4`?

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

in Cake we don't have recursive 4. recursive used for associated tables which are associated to current table (other meaning Model behavior) which can be between -1 to 2.

and also regarding to your table structure. please read the cake documents here to see which one one this is suits your table structure. In cake we have 3 kind of model structure. e.g. $actsAs = Tree or Containable or Translate

look at these question and article also:

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482113/how-to-set-containable-behavior-cakephp2-x)

[Reference 2](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations)

[Reference 3](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)